# Exclude Category filter from Portfolio section

Tags: wp-query, categories, exclude

I am stuck with this since hours and found lots of forum entries about `NOT IN`, `WP_Query`, `category__not_in` portfolio, editing JS/ CSS in Theme options or having bits of code to add to `portfolio.php`, but nothing seems to work.

In my head this should be a simple task to just define: exclude x or only display x but is beyond my PHP skills.

All I want is to exclude one filter/ category form the portfolio page. The rest can stay and be displayed as is.

Do I need to change it here or would it be helpful to have the full `portfolio.php` code? Or can I go via JS/ CSS?

```
<?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'project',
);
```